# What regex would match this starting from 0.5 to 24

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that would match this range: **0.5** - **24**, but not this: **0,5** or **22,5**. For now I have this one:

```
/^(([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])([^,])(\.(0|5)))$/
```

but for some reason it matches this 22,5 even though I negated the `,`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to only allow the dot and make a last capture group optional.
Like this:

```
/^([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(\.[05])?$/
```

`(\.[05])?` <- this allows, by the ? symbol, one or zero ocurrences of the second capture group.

Comment: Indeed. Updating answer.

Comment: Not sure if that is intentional, but it will also match 0 https://regex101.com/r/Y4pjyU/1

Comment: I would set up a special option for that case to avoid the 0 if needed: `^(([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(\.[05])?|0\.5)$`

Answer (score 0):

In terms of regular expressions, this will suit your needs.

```
^((0\.[5-9])|(([1-9](\.[5-9])?)|(1[0-9](\.[5-9])?)|(2[0-3](\.[5-9])?)|24))$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Jagl82/1)

However, if what you want is to check a range, I would advise you to use regular expressions just to check if the number is valid, and then, convert it and use plain javascript for your validation.

```js
var validator = function(value) {
  var regexp = /^-?\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
  var isNumber = regexp.test(value);
  if (isNumber) {
    var parsed = parseFloat(value);
    if (0.5 <= parsed && parsed <= 24)
      console.log("The number " + parsed + " is within range");
    else
      console.log("The number " + parsed + " is NOT within range");
  } else {
    console.log("The value " + value + " is NOT even a valid decimal value");
  }
}

validator("-3");
validator("19.6");
validator("22,5");
```